# How to write SQL Query, for avoiding duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
ID     Balance      Account Type      Date
1245    100           HR              01-01-15
1245    500           HC              02-01-15
1325    200           HC              03-01-15
1789    400           HC              04-01-15
```

In this case, I want only rows With account type as HC and Balance not equal to zero

```
select * from ABC where Account Type = 'HC'
and Balance<>0;
```

is not working.

I want only ID which has account type as HC and Balance > 0 and for that ID it should not have Account type as HR.

Comment: This query is running on MySql or Sql Server?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from ABC
where Account_Type = 'HC'
and Balance<>0
and not exists(
    select 'HR'
    FROM abc a2
    where a2.account_type = 'HR'
   AND a2.id = abc.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * 
from ABC A1 
where 
  Account Type = 'HC' and 
  Balance<>0 and 
  not exists (
    select 1 
    from ABC A2 
    where 
      A1.ID = A2.ID And 
      A2.Type = 'HR'
  )
```